# Compile Code with target:module switch

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, .net-assembly, referenceerror

I'm going to compile my code with the /target:module switch,

```
csc /target:module  ModuleName
```

But, In the module, I have references to other assembly and 
it get error `CS0246`: type of reference could not found

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the /lib switch. This specifies the location of assemblies referenced by means of the /reference (C# Compiler Options) option.

You can explicitly specify the reference dll's and where the compiler can find these assemblies for example:

```
csc /lib:c:\MyAssemblies /reference:assembly1.dll sourcefile.cs /target:module  ModuleName
```